# Reverting to Firefox 4 from Firefox 6 (alpha)

Tags: firefox

I recently downloaded Firefox 6 Aurora (alpha).  But this version does not have Firebug extension compatible with it.  I cannot re-install Firefox 4 as it's download is blocked (company policy).  Is there any way I can revert to firefox 4 by means of updates?

Thanks.
Sid

Comment: Those Firefox folks are completely off their rocker nowadays. Firefox 5 isn't even ready for release yet. Why are they dedicating resources to developing version 6? You're not going to beat Chrome by screwing up priorities.

Comment: Stop trying to circumvent IT policy at your workplace. At worst you'll be terminated, at best you'll piss off the people that control your access to everything.

Comment: Install Firefox 4 just like you did it the you installed it the first time?

Comment: @Daniel Beck - First time when I installed Firefox, it was not blocked.

Comment: @SidCool - Did they block your access for installing alpha software?  Go back to IT and tell them you screwed up and need to install a browser that works.

Comment: No.  It's a company wide policy that they enforced last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately this is not possible. There is no way to "update" from Firefox 6 to Firefox 4.

Not only does that defy intuition (such would not be an update!), but it's technically impossible as well. The code base for version 6 is undoubtedly very different from the code base for version 4.

Download and install version 4 the same way you were able to download and install the alpha release of version 6. That wasn't an in-place upgrade, either. Use the same methods to get around your company's security policy, or ask your administrator to do so for you.

Answer (score 1):

Normally different Firefox version are installed side by side. Maybe you still have Firefox 4 on you drive?

Comment: If you could edit your answer to say where he might look for the older version, that would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get Firebug for that verison of Firefox:

[Check out this blog post](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/05/firebug-for-firefox5aurora-get-version-1-8/)

Comment: It did not work.  It still says Firebug is not compatible.